# req.logIn is not passing user to req.user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

So I have this code

```
req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        req.session.flashData = {
          message: {
            type: 'error',
            body: 'Login failed'
          }
        }
      }
      return res.redirect('/homepage')
    })
```

but it does not pass user to req user

I tried setting req.user manually, like

`req.user=req.session.user`

but then `isAuthenticated()` always returns as false

btw my cookies are set to not secure